# TypeScript: Show an error when an external function returns a type of 'any'?

Tags: typescript, any

For example, the function `JSON.parse(data)` returns a type of `any`. So if you write something like this:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse('example');

console.log(parsed.somethingThatDoesntExist);
```

No error occurs in VSCode, despite having `noImplicitAny` set to `true` in my `tsconfig.json`, and my `.eslintrc.js` having the rule `'@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error'`.

I have also tried adding the following rules to my `eslintrc.js`, however they seem to break all TypeScript error checking:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'error',
```

In an ideal world I would want this `any` to be presumed to be `unknown`, but an error would also be great.

Here is my `eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2021,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        trailingComma: 'all',
        tabWidth: 2,
        semi: true,
        singleQuote: true,
        bracketSpacing: true,
        printWidth: 120,
        endOfLine: 'auto',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "ES2021.String"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../build/",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "composite": true,
    "types": [],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not set a type on the call to JSON.parse()?

Comment: let parsed: MyType = JSON.parse('example')

Comment: The reason that I want this is that I don't want to have a variable with type `any` by mistake. I want to be warned that I'm receiving a variable with type `any`. Of course, I would do that but I want to be told that I'm doing something wrong when there's an `any` involved.

Comment: You could set a type of `unknown` and then unless you cast the response from JSON.parse() to a known type, a warning will be shown. Would that help?

Comment: Yea, it would help. But the point is I don't want to accidentally not do that and have an "any" roaming around in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be to override any libraries where you want an explicit type. Generally the built-ins are typed well (with the exception of JSON.parse), but this could be helpful if you want to fix a broken or stubbed type from an external library.

For global (or built-ins) in a `global.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
  interface JSON {
    parse<T>(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => T): T
  }
}

export {} //this is needed to make it a module
```

Or a different syntax for modules

```js
declare module 'fooLibrary' {
  declare function bar<T>(): T
}
// IE. require('fooLibrary') or import * from ('fooLibrary')
```

And now when you try to use `JSON.parse`

```js
const foo = JSON.parse('test');
//   ^type? => unknown
const bar = JSON.parse<Record<string, any>>(...);
//   ^type? => Record<string, any>
```

[View working example on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0a2w)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a compiler option or similarly global solution that gives the result you want. However, you can craft an assertion function that disallows `any` on a specific expression:

```
type NotAny<T> = 0 extends 1 & T ? never : unknown
declare function assertNotAny<T extends NotAny<T>>(value: T): void

assertNotAny('"example"') // okay
assertNotAny(JSON.parse('"example"')) // error
```

This uses the fact that `any` cannot be assigned to `never`. By making a conditional type that resolves to `never`, you can cause a type error when `any` is passed in.

For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385024/480608