# How to cause a type error when a function returns any?

Tags: typescript

How do I cause TypeScript to throw an error when a specific function returns `any`?

I can hover over the function name in my editor to view the return type, but it would be nicer to get an error or warning. Often I'm working on a complex function with various generics and index types. I think I finally get the types right when actually there is an errant `any` that was inferred when my type expression was not narrowed properly.

Ideally this would take the form of a simple statement that I could leave in the code to ensure there are no regressions.

```js
function getNumber (): number { return 0; }
function getAny (): any { return 0; }

// Is there a simple, assert-like statement that will 
// succeed on getNumber and fail on getAny?
```

*Note: I am not looking for a compiler option. For simplicity I am explicitly setting any as the return type of `getAny`, but a real-world function could very well infer any in a less obvious way. Also, it's possible that I cannot add `noImplicitAny` without causing a rash of other errors in the project. The need for a simple, targeted expression that fails on `any` remains.*

Comment: That's not a type error, you need a _linter_: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any

Comment: As mentioned, I am looking for something that can cause a type/lint error on <strike>implicit</strike> inferred any.

Comment: Then set https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny, but that's not your example.

Comment: Actually, I'm not looking to error on *implicit* or *explicit* any, but rather error on *inferred* any. This can occur during development when failing to narrow a type properly. Regardless, my question makes it quite clear what I am asking for: A typescript statement that causes a type error when a function returns `any`.

Comment: I can totally appreciate your assumption that I am perhaps "asking the wrong question". This is a common occurrence with less experienced developers. But I would like to reassert that this is a valid, technical question about Typescript expressions. It is *not* a question about Typescript compiler options.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJrrVW) using the `any`-detector from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49927523/2887218) meet your needs?  Or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that works. It's about the same complexity as my answer below, but it's a novel approach.

Comment: Do you want me to write it up as an answer? If it's "about the same complexity" as your answer maybe it doesn't add much value

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think it's a better answer than mine since the actual assertion is so clean. For the purpose of this question, the any-detector can be simplified to `type NotAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? never : unknown;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Disallow call with any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49927523/2887218) but distinct enough that I'm not inclined to just close it as a duplicate.  Like in the answer to that question, you can build an "`any`-detector" by taking advantage of the fact that it is intentionally unsound and [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `any` also yield `any` (see [Type intersections using any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46673558/2887218)).  We can write

```
type NotAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? never : unknown;
```

so that `NotAny<any>` is `never`, but `NonAny<X>` for any other type `X` is `unknown`.  (If you have a non-`any` type `X`, the type `1 & X` will be a non-`any` subtype of `1`, and `0` does not extend `1`.  But `1 & any` is just `any`, and `0 extends any`.)

Then you can use that detector as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on your assertion function:

```
declare function doesNotReturnAny<T extends NotAny<T>>(fn: (...args: any) => T): void;

doesNotReturnAny(getNumber); // okay
doesNotReturnAny(getAny); // error
```

This works because, as mentioned, the only type `any` is *not* assignable to is `never`.  So `getNumber` causes `T` to be inferred as `number`, and `number` is assignable to `unknown`, but `getAny` causes `T` to be inferred as `any`, and `any` is not assignable to `never`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgOYFMYDkwFsBG6ATgBQCUAXMhHoUcgN7JGZhEoAMA3MgL6iRYiFBhgBBCAE9yVAIZTGfYMoD0K5DEkAHdMgCSICZIA8AFQA0yAJqWsAPmQBeZB2ToAHjHQQAJgGdkEgBGZAAyZFMyZAB+a2QqLC5gTR1kLARxKTMHZ1cPL18A4LCIqNiIdAA3YnjkSABrCAQAdwgkn3QoABtZFmRwaHgkZB8EdD90mAAlVnYjMzdPb380jPnTOzsSEAgqEgA6Q97UPzkpKMcHSKpKhDgfJOBR8cmZmDYIIxJRHAJiMieYwmGTeHy+oiMAOAQA)

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but I would be very interested in terser alternatives.

Typescript will throw an error if you try to assign `any` to a `never` variable. So you can set up a failing assertion by getting the intersection of the return type and a unique symbol type that has no overlap. Importantly, this will always evaluate to `never`, unless the return type is `any`.

```
const NEVER_SYMBOL = Symbol('NeverSymbol')
type NeverSymbol = typeof NEVER_SYMBOL

function getNumber () { return 0; }
function getAny (): any {}

// passes because NeverSymbol & number === never
const a: never = NEVER_SYMBOL as NeverSymbol & ReturnType<typeof getNumber>

// fails because NeverSymbol & any === any (intended)
// Is there an easier way?
const b: never = NEVER_SYMBOL as NeverSymbol & ReturnType<typeof getAny>
```

[View in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAcgUQGoIEoH0DKBNAsgIQHkAZGAXhkwE8BbAIxABsAKAcjgFMA3DgJ2vpNWASgBQUKgAcO8bnwENG5GBOkgAZvGRoseIsVGj1AVzDAoAS3AwA5hyhxj9PjGbCYAbxi97x3mBgABgBuGABfI1NzKwC7KABBMCpXYQAuGABDJM8I0QB6PJhJDIgIDggYOg5gDOMy2R5+WkUYADIYMCcq3nIyCjA5XlFQSFgM9IHG5UQUDBwCEkyKzkaFJjaYVF9-ABUpDgAeVQ4NW3tHZ14APkMCmHUMi0YKqpq6mRX5ZvX2rOS+ih-VwWMBQDhgAAmHAhYjuAEkKlAABZ8GRZGAcEoWFwAdwyVAA-MNwNBKhNBtNtHM9IsSg0voIlO0tlA-GA9tIjvtTnFElQbkA)